# gdal_calc.py Error: could not open file "a.geo"

Tags: anaconda, gdal

I've had a problem with gdal_calc for a few days that I didn't have before.
Basically, I should recalculate a GEO file and I've always used (via Anaconda Prompt):

```
python %CONDA_PREFIX%\Scripts\gdal_calc.py -A myfile.geo --outfile mynewfile.geo --calc="-(A*5/7)" --format=ENVI --NoDataValue=-9999 --overwrite
```

I've never had any problems, but since a few days, trying to convert a GEO file I get:

```
could not open file "file.geo"
```

I tried to convert the initially converted files back without problems and:

- pressing Enter, I get nothing
- I get the same error

I would like to understand where the problem could be.
I state that I have not made any changes to the path of the GDAL and Anaconda files

Comment: Try `--outfile=mynewfile.geo`

Comment: Nothing changes, I fixed it by creating an .hdr file associated with my GEO file